# $f$ is a decreasing function whose integral converges. Does $\lim_{x \to \infty}xf(x) = 0$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, integral, function, calculus

My finals are over and I cannot help but ruminate over this particular problem. Could anyone help prove this?

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f(t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ converges.  Prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} xf(x)=0.$$

Comment: What is the statistical component? This looks like pure calculus.

Comment: Whether here or on our sister site [math.SE], you should show what you've attempted so far and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: @Dave This question has a statistical application when $f$ is the survival function of a (continuous) non-negative variable.   The supposition about the integral means this variable has a finite expectation.  This alone gives us insight, because it reveals continuity is not a necessary assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's unnecessary for a solution, let's connect the elements of this question to familiar statistical concepts.

Because $f$ is continuous and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ it behaves like some multiple of a [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) for a distribution.  We can turn it into one by ensuring none of its values exceed $1.$  Since the continuity and decreasing properties imply $f(0)$ is finite, and if $f(0)=0$ the conclusion follows immediately, let's suppose $f(0)\gt 0$ and for all $t\ge 0$ define

$$S(t) = \frac{1}{f(0)} f(t).$$

This makes $S$ the survival function of a *continuous* distribution, because we can extend it to a continuous non-increasing function on all real numbers by setting $S(x)=1$ for all $x\lt 0.$

In light of this, *we ought to begin to wonder whether the continuity assumption on $f$ is really necessary:* perhaps the result is true of any survival function.

**Let's turn to the question by proving the contrapositive:** if $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)$ is nonzero or does not exist, that implies $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ does not converge.

Now because all $x f(x)$ are non-negative when $x\gt 0,$ the failure of $x f(x)$ to have zero as a limit means there must be a positive threshold $\epsilon$ that is exceeded by $x f(x)$ at an unbounded sequence of positive points.  The unboundedness implies we may select a subsequence  $x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \ldots \lt x_n \lt \ldots$ for which $x_{n+1} \ge 2x_n$ for all $n;$ that is,

$$\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{x_{n+1}}\ge \frac{1}{2}.$$

For all of these points, because $x_n f(x_n)\ge \epsilon$ and $x_n\gt 0,$

$$f(x_n) \ge \frac{\epsilon}{x_n},\ n=1, 2, 3, \ldots$$

Moreover, on each interval $(x_n, x_{n+1}],$ $f(x) \ge f(x_{n+1})$ (because $f$ is not increasing).  Combining this with the preceding inequality gives

$$f(x) \ge f(x_{n+1}) \ge \frac{\epsilon}{x_{n+1}} \text{ when } x_n \lt x \le x_{n+1}.$$

Use this as a lower bound to estimate the integral, breaking it into integrals over the intervals between the $x_n$ (and just ignoring the initial interval from $0$ to $x_1$):

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t &= \int_0^{x_1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} \frac{\epsilon}{x_{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \epsilon\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}{x_{n+1}}\\
& \ge \epsilon\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2},
\end{aligned}$$

which diverges. Therefore $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ must diverge too.  **This negation of the convergence assumption completes the proof.**

Looking back over the assumptions needed for this analysis, we find that the continuity of $f$ was not needed anywhere: it sufficed that $f$ was *nondecreasing* and *non-negative.*  Consequently, *this result holds for all survival functions.*